# HTTP GET request vs Port request (Speed)

Tags: php, get, port

I have a strange question but maybe not so strange.

I'm doing a script to hit my server to get some data from my DB. Now my question with regards to speed, reliability and connection amount is, what is the best?

1) To do a GET request strait to a URL (www.example.com/request.php)
or
2) To do a request to the server with a custom port (123.123.123.123:5555)

The thing is that it must always be online. That is crucial to my development.

Comment: Direct IP is quicker because no DNS resolution is required. Direct IP is also prone to failure because 1 IP = 1 machine, so if something happens to anything in the communication chain - bye bye script. A domain name can be round-robined to multiple IPs so you can always have a responsive script, even if one of the IPs it runs on is unreachable. Basically, for real world - you never access something via IP, if it's not intra-network / cluster. That's why we have domain names after all.

Comment: What do you mean by "speed"? If one snail is 20% faster than other snails, is it fast?

Answer (score 0):

Technically an IP is faster than a domain name, but the IP is not very recommended in case of Quality Code.

If you really want to use an IP, consider making a constant so that it can easily configured in case of changes in IP and Code Quality.